# What is a good website to check when a javascript object/method appeared across browsers?

Tags: javascript

Where can I check when was a specific javascript object or method introduced to all major browsers?

E.g. I just though I had a horrible production bug for a week because the Safari I just downloaded fails on JSON.stringify(), but then discovered I had somehow download an ancient Safari version, and the latest Safari versions do support it. Where can I find when exactly did Safari add JSON.stringify()?

**Bonus:** This is how I got lured into download a Safari version from three years ago. WTF?

[image]

Comment: http://kangax.github.com/es5-compat-table/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://caniuse.com is also a great source of such information.

Answer (score 1):

Well there's http://www.quirksmode.com

(*Much* more general but covering many more browsers is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Browser_features)